# PDF genearte and download in single click

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdf, download

If anyone done PDF generate and download in single click?

I done the PDF generate but i cant download. Please send any suggestion

```
$this->load->library('provab_pdf');
                    $create_pdf = new Provab_Pdf();
                    $get_view=$this->template->isolated_view('voucher/flight_ticket', $page_data);
                    $values=$create_pdf->create_pdf($get_view,'show');
```

This is the code i added for generate to PDF

Is this had idea to download the PDF?

Comment: $values is the content of your PDF document?

Comment: yes  maxime_039 $values is my PDF

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy use `TCPDF`  instead `provab_pdf` 
[Check Out Here An Example Of TCPDF with Codeigniter](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/TCPDF-Integration)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with something similar to my code below. You have to define the file name and retrieve the size of your file.

```
$fileName = "your file name";
$fileSize = "your file size";

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Length: " . $fileSize);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');

// Allow caching
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 6400) . " GMT"; // 24 * 60 * 60, caching for one day
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=" . 6400 . ", private");

readfile($values);

exit();
```

If you have a file path, you can determine the file size by using:

```
filesize($filePath);
```

And the read file would then be:

```
readfile($filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get your flow with JsPDF. Saved me mighty.